# Category of elements over small category: is it small?

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a [small category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/small+category), and let $F:C\to \mathrm{Set}$ be a set-valued functor. 
Is the [category of elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_elements) of $F$ small?

If yes, how does one show that the arrows form a (small) set? (For the objects I have more intuition.)

Comment: As a hint, the arrows of this category will just be a subset of $\mathrm{Mor}(C)\times\coprod_{c\in C}F(c)$.